# Cutting image in smaller pieces Python or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, image-processing

Is there any way to cut an image into smaller pieces using JavaScript? Like, if the user clicks on a button for example, the image (initial dimensions are 100x100 for example) will be cut into 10 pieces of 10x10, and if they click more, those small pieces will be cut in more and smaller pieces as well. So it's same operation called in a recursive way. Is there any JavaScript image manipulation library or anything? 
Or is it possible to do the same thing using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as klaus mentioned, ImageMagick for python, and for javascript, try looking into the canvas;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images there is a section on slicing images

Comment: So I just have to do a recursive call to the DrawImage method (for slicing) and i'm done? sounds awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the **crop** functions in [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) (no, it's not JavaScript) or the [Python Imaging Library](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).